# Is it possible to use VBA to make the Conditional Formatting box larger? If so how?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I think this code is used to resize the application window, but I want to make the conditional formatting manager box larger.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.WindowState = xlNormal
Application.Top = 25
Application.Left = 25
Application.Width = 300
Application.Height = 200
End Sub
```

My goal for this code is to be able to view all the conditional formatting rules and their associated formats for screenshotting/printing so they can be documented. I have since found code to print all CF rules but the code is (obviously) incapable of printing what the format looks like since formats are non-textual.

Comment: Are you wanting to apply your conditional formatting to a larger range? Or make the actual "Conditional Formatting Rules Manager" display in a larger window?

Comment: Using pure VBA, no. Using Win32 API hacks, maybe. You really want to go there?

Comment: I don't think it's possible at all. (Why is it so hard to have resizable windows, @Microsoft?). You might want to include your Excel version, though.

Comment: @oxwilder, I want to be able to view the whole rule, what it's supposed to format like, and what cells it applies to for printing and documentation purposes.

Comment: @Mathieu Guidon, No lol

Comment: @Inarion, sorry I'm using 2013.

Comment: Regarding your comment to oxwilder, you could edit your question to mention your goal. I think creating a macro that will print all information about conditional formatting to a worksheet is well possible. You could then format that sheet and print it to pdf/paper/whatever. It might even be possible to have a preview of what the format looks like this way. :)

Comment: I have actually found some code that prints all the conditional formatting rules - its only drawback is that it cannot print what the format of the boxes look like in terms of colors and borders.

Comment: That's a good start. Can you add a link to the source? I might be able to expand on it with some formatting display. Not really sure on that, but I'd like to try.

Answer (score 0):

This can now be done natively.

New versions of Excel now let you resize the conditional formatting manager box.

For more information and version requirements see [Conditional formatting improvements](https://www.excelquicker.com/resources/news-sheet/conditional-formatting-improvements/).